# Error updating Swift 1 array code to Swift 2

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2

Hello i have just updated to swift 2 and i the following error in my array:
'NSMutableArray' is not implicitly convertible to '[AnyObject]'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?

```
func addAlien(){

    var alien:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cuadradoRojo")
    alien.name = "alien"
    alien.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: alien.size.width/2)
    alien.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    var actionArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    var actionArray2:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    alien.removeFromParent()
    var alienAzul:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cuadradoAzul")
    alienAzul.name = "alien"
    alienAzul.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: alien.size.width/2)
    alienAzul.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    alienAzul.removeFromParent()
    if gameOver == false{


        let minX = alien.size.width/2

        let maxX = self.frame.size.width - alien.size.width/2

        let rangeX = maxX - minX
        let position:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random()) % CGFloat(rangeX) + CGFloat(minX)

        alien.position = CGPointMake(position, self.frame.size.height + alien.size.height)
        alienAzul.position = CGPointMake(position, self.frame.size.height + alienAzul.size.height)
        var randomCirculo = arc4random_uniform(2)
        if randomCirculo == 0{
            self.addChild(alienAzul)
        }
        else {
            addChild(alien)
        }

        let minDuration = 3


        let duration = Int(minDuration)



        actionArray.addObject(SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(position, -alien.size.height), duration: NSTimeInterval(duration)))

        actionArray.addObject(SKAction.removeFromParent())
        actionArray2.addObject(SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(position, -alienAzul.size.height), duration: NSTimeInterval(duration)))

        actionArray2.addObject(SKAction.removeFromParent())

        alien.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray as [AnyObject]))
        alienAzul.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray as [AnyObject]))

    }    
}
```

I GOT THE ERROR DOWN HERE alien.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray as [AnyObject])) alienAzul.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray as [AnyObject]))

Comment: Where did you get the error – and what happened when you followed the compiler's advice?

Comment: When i follow the compilers advice it gives me this error: Cannot convert value of type '[AnyObject]' to expected argument type '[SKAction]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
var actionArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
```

use

```
var actionArray = [SKAction]()
```

ObjectiveC has been updated to support generics NSArray and most of the frameworks have been updated accordingly.

`SKAction.sequence(NSArray)` has been changed to `SKAction.sequence(Array<SKAction>)` in Swift, or `SKAction.sequence(NSArray<SKAction*>*)` in ObjC.

Comment: Thanks. Where can i find all this changes?

Comment: Good question. There is this [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-401/), the [Swift Blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/) and the API reference pages in general.

Comment: Also, there is a migration tool in XCode7 for converting a project to Swift2, which is doing a pretty decent job.